# Dynamically constructed ui-sref attribute in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular and especially ui-router.

Here is a link:

```
<a ui-sref="/topic/{{topic.id}}">SomeText</a>
```

The link is dynamically populated.

So when I try to access that state from my config like this:

```
 .state('topics/:topicId',{
        url:"",
        templateUrl: "",
        controller: ""
    })
```

I get this error message:

> Error: Could not resolve '/topics/myTopic' from state 'topics'

In the above: `myTopic` is a variable name.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are almost there. Just the parameter must be part of the URL definition, not the name of the state:

```
.state('topics',{
    url: '/{id:[0-9]{1,8}}', // we can also add some constraint, like int id only
    templateUrl: "",
    controller: ""
 })
```

And how to call it *(where `currentItem.id` would be injected dynamically as a part of some ng-repeat)*

```
<a ui-sref="topics({id:currentItem.id})">SomeText</a>
```

Because `ui-sref` means: `ui-sref='stateName({param: value, param: value})`. More info here:

- [ui router, URL Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters)
- [ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)

Comment: Explanation was nice. More importantly thanks for the docs link.

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) Enjoy Angular `ui-router`, awesome feature ;)

Comment: Hey I have one more question. Take a look at it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23500923/data-obtained-from-http-service-cant-be-obtained-from-ng-click

Answer (score 8):

Try to use a simple name for state as `'topics'` and use `'topics/:topicId'` as url property.
After that you can use `ui-sref='topics({topicId: topic.id})'`