# data obtained from $http service cant be obtained from ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a part of my `controller`:

```
function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $timeout, $q, $ionicPopup, $ionicActionSheet){
    $http.get('topics/' + $stateParams.subTopicId + '.json').
    success(function(data, status,header, config) {
        $scope.questions = data;
    });
}
```

Now here is a part of my `view`:

```
<button ng-click="someFunc('{{questions[qNum].opt1}}')">
    {{questions[0].opt1}} 
</button>

In the above view {{questions[0].opt1}} works perfectly. But when passed as an arg to ng-click it becomes empty.
```

And again in my `controller`:

```
 function someFunc(aValue){
        alert(aValue); // Empty
    }
```

Why is the value of the variable `aValue` empty.

On the other hand if, I directly declare `$scope.questions` inside my controller like this:

```
$scope.question = [
                   { ... }
                  ];
```

Then `someFunc` displays the value of the variable correctly. What is going on here?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the content of `aValue` inside `someFunc` really empty? Because, on the view, you are explicitly passing string *(it is enclosed in '' so it is just a pure string... while looking like expression `'{{questions[qNum].opt1}}'`)*. Also, the *question(s)* loaded via $http vs declared in scope -- is it really different? Then also check the content of the returned data... it could have some wrapper object like `data.d.results`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button ng-click="someFunc(questions[qNum].opt1)">
```

Also, you are explicitly binding to element 0 when showing the property, but in your ng-click you are using a variable qNum, so be sure that is defined.

Comment: Wait i will try it. Power cut right now. That is a typo i guess. I have qnum defined in controller.

Comment: It worked. What was I doing wrong while using service?

Comment: Not sure if I have all the terminology right, but you had a binding expression inside a directive parameter, which is already an expression.