# Angular ng-repeat error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

So my HTML is:

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="test in tests">
    <a ui-sref="test{{id: test._id}}"><pre>{{test._id}}</pre></a>
</div>
```

My router config in app.js

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: ""
        })
        .state('new', {
            url: "/new",
            templateUrl: "templates/new.html"
        })
        .state('test', {
            url: "/tests/:id",
            templateUrl: "templates/test.html"
        })
});
```

I have an error which console throw

> Error: Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 3 of the expression [id: test._id] starting at [: test._id].
>       at Error (native)
>   What the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to send parameter is like a function - enclosed them in braces `test({..})`

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="test in tests">
    <a ui-sref="test({id: test._id})"><pre>{{test._id}}</pre></a>
</div>
```

Similar issue: [Dynamically constructed ui-sref attribute in ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476296/)

Comment: Great if that helped: here is a link to documentation http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref